# C# How to programmatically tab between controls

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to programmatically emulate the keyboard
navigation for dialog boxes.

I have a custom hardware device with a keypad that I would like to use for
dialog box navigation.

I know about Focus(), but I'd rather do something that automatically
respected the tab order.  By emulating the keyboard navigation I don't
have to worry about re-inventing complex behavior for each type of
control.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, they were all great answers, and so quick too.  I went with Thomas's suggestion since it fit in well with my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use P/Invoke to call the Windows API function [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) to simulate pressing the Tab key.

Bonus: you can use your device to enter tabs into a text editor as well! ;)

Answer (score 12):

For Winforms, you want want the [`Control.GetNextControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol.aspx) method

For WPF, you want the [`UIElement.MoveFocus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.movefocus.aspx) method

Answer (score 9):

In Winforms:

```
Control nextControl = this.GetNextControl(myControl, true);
```

To simulate a tab press, I believe it's the following:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```